# How would I use REGEX to find a set of unique words within a range using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, jruby

I'm looking to create a Regex which meets the following requirements:

1) Must act as an "AND" statement

2) Both words should be in a range of eachother

3) It does not count two of the same word.

So far, I have this working REGEX, which satisfies 1 and 2.

```
/(word1|word2)(?:\W+\w+){0,3}?\W+(word1|word2)/i
```

Example Regex:
`/(cat|dog)(?:\W+\w+){0,3}?\W+(cat|dog)/i`

**Strings That Work Now**

- The cat scared the other cat.
- The cat likes the dog.
- The dog likes the cat.
- The dog hates the dog.

**Strings That I Don't Want**

- The cat scared the other cat.
- The dog hates the dog.

A phrase such as "The cat scared the other cat." would match this REGEX because it is searching for any word in the second grouping, which includes cat. I do not want it to search for itself, however. I want it only to search for dog.

Comment: 2) what is it mean *of each other*?

Comment: Word1 should be within three words of Word2. This actually works already. My problem is that word1 is looking for itself (word1) in addition to looking for word2. I just want it to look for word2 but not word1, while keeping the three word range.

Comment: Your requirements are unclear, can you add several example strings with the result you hope for each.

Comment: Sure, just did! Basically, I'm trying to avoid having one word search for the same word.

Comment: Does it have to be a regex, or is using a parser also acceptable?

Comment: Regex, however, M42 just solved it and gave a good explanation as well! I was missing this- (?!\1) - which ensures that the first capture is not to be looked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
/(cat|dog)(?:\W+\w+){0,3}?\W+(?!\1)(cat|dog)/
```

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:(cat|dog)(?:\W+\w+){0,3}?\W+(?!\1)(cat|dog))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    cat                      'cat'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    dog                      'dog'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (between 0 and 3
                           times (matching the least amount
                           possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \W+                      non-word characters (all but a-z, A-Z,
                             0-9, _) (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){0,3}?                  end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \W+                      non-word characters (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-
                           9, _) (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \1                       what was matched by capture \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    cat                      'cat'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    dog                      'dog'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I want. I tested it on Rubular to be sure. Thanks!

Comment: I find that regex offensive.

Comment: If the explanation is from a regex-tester (e.g. Rubular), which one?  @Damian, I'm a little slow on the uptake this morning.  More than just friends?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: It's a CPAN module http://search.cpan.org/~gsullivan/YAPE-Regex-Explain-4.01/Explain.pm